# SKlean's LassoCV with regularization parameter per target

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, lasso-regression

For linear regressions, alphas (regularization parameters) are usually obtained via cross-validation.

My goal is to perform regression for each target dimension. So that the alpha is defined for each target dim. Assuming that my input data size is `100 x 10` and target data size is `100 x 3` (`n_sample x dim`), I want to get three alphas for each target dim.

For this, `sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV` has `alpha_per_target`. If `alpha_per_target` is set True, then the alphas are assigned for each target dim.

However, there is no such thing in `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV`. I think I understand what Lasso and Ridge regression are. But I don't understand why the LassoCV in sklearn does not have something similar to `alpha_per_target` from RidgeCV. Perhaps I misunderstood the concepts so that applying `alpha_per_target` to LassoCV is totally nonsense.

Could anyone help me understand why something like `alpha_per_target` is not implemented in LassoCV? Is it because it does not make sense? or is it simply not implemented yet?

References

- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html
- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html